# How do you find documentation for Splice Machine?

Tags: hadoop

How do I find documentation on Splice Machine?

Comment: Googling "splice machine documentation" returned the answer to your question as the first result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is found at http://doc.splicemachine.com.  For using the Open Source, refer to the README.md under https://github.com/splicemachine/spliceengine

Comment: Thanks Gene!  I'm importing data and see that I need to specify a time stamp format.  Does the format need to be the same for every record in the file I am importing?

Comment: Yes.  You can see the full details for importing at http://doc.splicemachine.com/SQLReference/BuiltInSysProcs/ImportData.html?Highlight=import_data